# Accessing JavaScript function variables outside of the function

Tags: javascript, parameters

I apoligize for my newbness but I'm not clearly understanding how to access variables within a function outside of the function. I understand that you need to pass them some how but I'm not 100% sure on the whys and hows.

Taking the below code for example, I want to use the `var degree` throughout the code outside of the function. How do I do it?

```
function DegreeToMil() 
{

//Degree's to Mils: 1 Degree = 17.777778 Mils

var degree = 10;
var mils = degree * 17.777778;

return mils;

 }
```

Comment: A bad answer would be to define it without the `var` which makes it global... a better answer would be to `return` the vars that you want to use at the end of the function

Comment: Yea I understand I can make it global but let's say this in this scenario i don't want to.

Comment: Then you can pass variables to the function, read them inside and do what you want to do, and at the end - return them - that would be a better approach.

Comment: So why can't I access the `var degree` by just typing `DegreeToMil.degree`

Comment: because even though a function is also sort-of an object in JS - you can't access it as such.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So if I wanted to use `degree` outside of the function <b> without returning it in the function </b> how would I do so? `function DegreeToMil (degree)`?

Comment: You would be passing degree to the function that way, so yes if you had it defined outside the function you could access whatever variable you made it to be.

Comment: Okay I think it's starting to make sense. So they only possible way to access a variable within a function is have the function itself return it. Correct?

Comment: @mwilson, that is incorrect. For example, you could have a closure that accesses the privately scoped variables.

Comment: Now I'm getting more lost. Let me rephrase my question again, then. How can I access the variable `degree` without defining it outside of DegreeToMil() and without having to `return` it

Comment: @mwilson I updated my answer below, so you can check it out. Note, unless you called `DegreesToMils()` with a defined parameter prior to attempting to access `DegreesToMils.degrees` without including the definition line I included above the function, it will resolve as `undefined`. You may or may not care about it. Also, I did try making it so you wouldn't need the line outside of the function, but it would have still required a function call first. If someone else knows another way I hope they share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually fairly simple, just define it outside of the function.

**Edit**: Updated with an example, and comments explaining what was done and how it works.

```
    DegreesToMils.degrees = 10; /* This is a static variable declaration to make sure it isn't undefined
                             * See note 1 below */

function DegreesToMils(degrees) {
    if (degrees !== undefined) {
        DegreesToMils.degrees = degrees; /* If the parameter is defined, 
                                          * it will update the static variable */
    }

    var milsPerDegree = 17.777778; /* This is a variable created and accessible within the function */

    return DegreesToMils.degrees * milsPerDegree; /* The function will return 177.77778 */
}

console.log(DegreesToMils.degrees); /* Prints 10, Note 1: This would be undefined if
                                     * not declared before the first call to DegreesToMils() with a 
                                     * defined parameter
                                     */
console.log(DegreesToMils(10)); /* Prints 177.77778 */
console.log(DegreesToMils(9)); /* Prints 160.00000200000002, Sets DegreesToMils.degrees to 9 */
console.log(DegreesToMils.degrees); /* Prints 9 */
```

Comment: I just wrote that this would be a bad answer :)

Comment: We posted at the same time ;)

I defined mils outside of the function using var, and assigned to it inside the function. Depending on the environment you are in, for example node.js, defining it as a var outside of the function will only make it global to the containing module, and will not put it in "global space".

Answer (score 1):

```
function DegreeToMil() 
{

    //Degree's to Mils: 1 Degree = 17.777778 Mils

    var degree = 10;
    var mils = degree * 17.777778;
    var result = [degree, mils]; // it's an array
    return result;
}

// use it like this

var myResult = DegreeToMil();
console.log(myResult[0]); // degree
console.log(myResult[1]); // mils
```

Comment: EDIT changed brackets to parens

Comment: So the only option for me to use `degree` outside of the function to `return` it?

Comment: what about `function DegreeToMil (degree)`?